# Spring Boot app with TCP socket thread - am I doing it correctly?

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-boot, autowired

I am running a Spring Boot app that receives data from IoT endpoints. It is a proprietary protocol, so I am just using a standard TCP socket implementation, based on [this example from Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html).

Currently I have a @Component that starts a new Thread:

```
@Component
public class TCPSocketServer {

  @Autowired
  private TCPServerRunnable sr;


  @PostConstruct
  public void init() throws IOException
  {
    sr.setSocket(new ServerSocket(43110));
    Thread server = new Thread(sr);
    server.start();
  }

  @PreDestroy
  public void clean()
  {
    // close any open sockets, resources, etc.
    sr.stop();
  }
}
```

and a server logic here, which starts a new Thread for every connection:

```
@Component
public class TCPServerRunnable implements Runnable {

  private ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
  private static boolean isRunning = true;
  @Autowired
  private VehicleService vehicleService = null;

  @Override
  public void run() {
    //TODO: Remove comments.
    System.out.println("TCP thread started...");
    while (isRunning) {
      System.out.println("Accepting new TCP connections...");
      try {
        new TCPServerRunnableHandler(serverSocket.accept(), vehicleService).start();
      } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("TCP socket creation failed...");
      }
      System.out.println("TCP connection established...");
    }
  }

  private static class TCPServerRunnableHandler extends Thread {

    private Socket clientSocket;
    private DataOutputStream out;
    private DataInputStream in;
    private VehicleService vehicleService;

    public TCPServerRunnableHandler(Socket socket, VehicleService vehicleService) {
      this.clientSocket = socket;
      this.vehicleService = vehicleService;
    }

    public void run() {
      try {
        out = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
        in = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());

        while (isRunning)  {
          byte[] data = new byte[512];
          int packetEnd = 0, i = 0;
          while (packetEnd < 2) {
            data[i] = in.readByte();
            if (data[i] == (byte)0xC0) {
              packetEnd++;
            } else {
              if (data[i] == (byte)0xDC && i > 0 && data[i-1] == (byte)0xDB) {
                data[i-1] = (byte)0xC0;
              } else {
                i++;
              }
            }
          }
          Protocol protocol = new Protocol(vehicleService);
          data = protocol.processMessage(data, clientSocket.getInetAddress().getHostAddress(), clientSocket.getPort());

          for (int j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
            if (data[j] == (byte) 0xC0 && j > 0) {
              out.writeByte(0xDB);
              out.writeByte(0xDC);
            } else {
              out.writeByte(data[i]);
            }
          }
          out.writeByte(0xC0);
          out.flush();
        }

        in.close();
        out.close();
        clientSocket.close();
      } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("TCP iot interface exception....");
      }
    }
  }

  void stop() {
    isRunning = false;
  }

  public void setSocket(ServerSocket socket) {
    this.serverSocket = socket;
  }
}
```

The problem I am having is that I do not know if the Protocol is the right class to use the @Service vehicleService that connects to a database and updates Vehicle fields based on the message received. The second issue is that I do not like the implementation of the Threads. I cannot autowire the Vehicle Service directly in the Protocol class, because it is not instantiated by Spring Boot.

Can you please give me some instructions on how should I approach those topics? Is there a better way to do the above in Spring Boot?

Thank you for any suggestions!!!

Comment: When you say "proprietary protocol", it sounds like you mean you designed it?

Comment: A "proper" way would be to use something like [spring-integration](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/basic/tcp-client-server) so you don't have to deal with the gritty details.

Comment: Spring offers asynchronous execution and scheduling of tasks with the TaskExecutor. i don't know if this can help but you might want to check this link. [spring_docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html)

Comment: @ElhoussineZennati what does that have to do with a TCP socket server?

Comment: it is threading using spring, not related to tcp socket server.

Comment: @daniu: I did not designed it. The company that created it is the only one using it.

Comment: @Kayaman - I have been reading about Spring Integration, but it seems so complicated, I do not know, how to start with it. Could you write me a part of the code I could start with?

Comment: There are plenty of excellent tutorials made by the Spring people.

Comment: @elhoussine-zennati : TaskExecutor is not for tasks? I want to have a constant process running, not a task.

Comment: @Kayaman - I was searching for anything usefull, but did not find anything. Can you recommend me one that could work in my case?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't find anything.

Comment: @Kayaman - Haha, the same thing happened to me. This is why I used sockets in the first place. Could you give me a hint, how to start writing it?

Answer (score 0):

I was looking to do something similar, except with pure Java socket. Here is my implementation, it has two advantages you might consider.

1. All objects are in the spring IOC
2. Threading is handled by java.util.concurrent.Executors

*Client*

```
@Component
public class SocketServer {

@Autowired
private SocketServerRunnable socketServerRunnable;

@PostConstruct
public void init() throws IOException {
    try (var listener = new ServerSocket(59898)) {
        System.out.println("The server is running...");
        var pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(100);

        //External Loop
        while (true) {
            socketServerRunnable.setSocket(listener.accept());
            pool.execute(socketServerRunnable);
        }
    }
}
```

*Server*

```
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
@Data
public class SocketServerRunnable implements Runnable {
private ServerSocket serverSocket;
private Socket socket;

@Override
public void run() {
    System.out.println("Connected: " + socket);
    try {
        DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        DataOutputStream dout = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        String str = "", str2 = "";
        while (!str.equals("stop")) {
            //gateway.route(din);
            str = din.readUTF();
            System.out.println("client says: " + str);
            str = din.readUTF();
            System.out.println("client says: " + str);
            str = din.readUTF();
            System.out.println("client says: " + str);
            str2 = br.readLine();
            dout.writeUTF(str2);
            dout.flush();
        }
        din.close();
        //socket.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```